# JS aren't objects saved in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have this script working with jquery and uploadify

```
      $('#uploader').uploadify({
    'uploader'  : '/admin/includes/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'script'    : '/admin/includes/uploadify/uploadify_storage.php',
     'scriptData': {'sessionId': sessionId},
    'cancelImg' : '/admin/includes/uploadify/cancel.png',
     'buttonImg'   : '/site_images/add_files.png',
    'folder'    :  storage,
    'auto'      : false,
    'multi'     : true,
    'fileExt'     : '*.jpg',
    'simUploadLimit' : 2,
    'wmode': 'transparent',
    'width': '150',
    'height': '20',
    'removeCompleted': false,
    'queueID'        : 'upload_queue',
    'onComplete'  : function(event, ID, fileObj, name,response, data) {

                             console.log(path);
             console.log(sub_ul);       
        }
  });

//code//


    $("li.dir > span.name").live('click', function(){
         $("span").removeClass("selected");
        var li = $(this).parent();
        var root  = $(li).attr("title");
        var folder  = $(li).find("span.name").html();
        var path = root+"/"+folder;
        path = path.replace('//', '/');
        var sub_ul = $(li).find("> ul.sub_folder");
                    set_path(sub_ul);
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    });
```

basically when I you click a span with `.name` it runs the code getting `var sub_ul = $(li).find("> ul.sub_folder");` which works (its sent to `set_path()` ) . In a second time when I launch uploadify at the end on `OnComplete` the `console.log(path);` shows the correct value but `console.log(sub_ul);` returns nothing (an alert too) like the object is not specified. I can't use objects after the JS has run? Don't they stay saved in the DOM like `path` does?

Comment: `var li = $(this).parent();` returns a jQuery object, there is no need to keep calling `$(li)`. You could also write: `var li = $(this.parentNode);`, which is more efficient (it creates one jQuery object instead of two and replaces a function call with a property access).

Comment: what do you mean there's no need to call $(li)? How should I put it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. <del>In the `onComplete` function that you've posted, you're logging `ul_sub` and not `sub_ul` as you seem to want to.</del>
2. Unless in `set_path()` you set the value for a global variable named `path`, I don't see how you would get the same value in those two different functions - the variable `path` within the `click` handler is scoped to that function and will not be accessible elsewhere. The same goes for `sub_ul`.
3. > I can't use objects after the JS has run? Don't they stay saved in the DOM like path does?

   I'm not quite sure what to make of this, JavaScript objects are not 'saved in the DOM'. If you're unable to access an object you've created, then the context must be different from the one the object was created in - it must now be out of scope and thus inaccessible. Using closure is one way to keep functions and variables accessible. Using global vars is another way to do it but is not recommended and should be avoided unless absolutely necessary.

---

You might want to read these articles about scope in JavaScript to get a better idea of how things work:

- http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/
- http://www.mredkj.com/tutorials/reference_js_intro_ex.html
- http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/

---

You've mentioned in the comments that you've made a global `path` variable but not a `sub_ul`. One simple way to 'fix' your code is to use global variables. But again, use of global variables is generally discouraged since you could end up polluting the global namespace.

And without seeing more of  your code, it's hard to say if this will always work correctly - for instance, your uploadify script might be triggered by events that do not cause the values of `path` and `sub_ul` to be set, which would mean that when the `onComplete` function runs, it'll get the wrong values for both.

```
//global vars
var path;
var sub_ul;

$('#uploader').uploadify({
    'uploader'  : '/admin/includes/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'script'    : '/admin/includes/uploadify/uploadify_storage.php',
     'scriptData': {'sessionId': sessionId},
    'cancelImg' : '/admin/includes/uploadify/cancel.png',
     'buttonImg'   : '/site_images/add_files.png',
    'folder'    :  storage,
    'auto'      : false,
    'multi'     : true,
    'fileExt'     : '*.jpg',
    'simUploadLimit' : 2,
    'wmode': 'transparent',
    'width': '150',
    'height': '20',
    'removeCompleted': false,
    'queueID'        : 'upload_queue',
    'onComplete'  : function(event, ID, fileObj, name,response, data) {
                        //these will now log the values of the global vars
                        console.log(path);
                        console.log(sub_ul);       
                    }
});

//code//


$("li.dir > span.name").live('click', function(){
    $("span").removeClass("selected");
    var li = $(this).parent();
    var root  = li.attr("title");
    var folder  = li.find("span.name").html();
    //don't redeclare path - that would shadow the global variable
    //use the global variable instead
    path = root+"/"+folder;
    path = path.replace('//', '/');
    //don't redeclare sub_ul
    sub_ul = $(li).find("> ul.sub_folder");
    set_path(sub_ul);
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

Comment: 1- that was just a typo sorry
2- path is already declared out of any functions, sub_ul is not, could it be that? :)
3 -I'm not sure I understood (I'm not very familiar with JS). What exactly should I do to use that object everywhere I want (even if its content changes?)
I did this `sub_ul =  new Object();` `sub_ul = $(li).find("> ul.sub_folder");` and it works, is this bad coding?

Comment: @Sandro 2. Yes, that's probably it - declaring `path` outside of any functions makes it a global variable, accessible everywhere 3. Well, you're creating a new object and assigning it to `sub_ul` but immediately overwriting that reference with the object returned by `$(li).find("> ul.sub_folder");` so it's pointless. Please see my updated answer for a quick and dirty fix. Also, do read the articles linked to in the answer - they should help clarify scope and lifetime of variables in JS.